# Script bash variables numericas

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo el siguiente código en un script bash de Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1

echo $2

res=$(($2+$1))

echo $res
```

Mi intención es que las variantes `$2` y `$1` se sumen, pero no está sucediendo, no sé cuál es el error, gracias.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, cambié el reglón 4 por: res=$((($2)+($1)))           agregando un paréntesis a cada referente

Comment: Ramiro, ponlo abajo como respuesta a tu pregunta, así los demás sabremos! De hecho, unas horas después puedes marcarla como aceptada, así los demás sabremos que tiene una solución que funciona.

Comment: A mi me funciona bien como lo tienes (bash en un mac, por si acaso... bash version 3.2.57).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta no utilizar ese tipo de nombres de variables dentro del *arithmetic expression*.

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
primer_valor="$1"
segundo_valor="$2"

resultado="$((primer_valor + segundo_valor))"
```

Y de esa manera te ahorras de malos entendidos con el intérprete y también eliminas los caracteres "$" sobrantes, ya que dentro de la *arithmetic expansion* se sobreentienden.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo solucioné, cambié el reglón 4 por:

```
res=$((($2)+($1)))
```

agregando un paréntesis a cada referente